# Excel 2007 Use one value to generate row

Tags: excel, excel-2007

As the title says,
I am building an Excel sheet in Excel 2007. Where do I need to have a value field (in my case 21, but it can be anything from 1 to...100? ) that would generate the columns from top till bottom like in my picture http://i45.tinypic.com/jqtkdk.jpg

The years need to change with it as well.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you would have to write a macro!

its quite easy!

you make a "for" loop from 1 to nr of rows you want,
then you put the value of the for loop in the first cell, and the second cell gets the value from the row above + 1 year! (you vould use a variable for this, not the row above..)

Comment: do you by any chance have an example? that would fit my needs?
i dont understand VB XD